# how to store selected tableview rows in an array?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I know there is better way to select a row then my way( which one welcome too). otherwise else I only need to know how to store selected rows from tableview ,when click Done button(bar item)

Note: in my tableview, I have multiple sections and if I select one row from one section, other section's rows will be  unselected.

## Edit 1

for more clarification,
suppose there are 3 sections, each section has 5 rows.

step1 : I select row1 and row2 in section1

step2: if I select any row from section 2 or section 3, section1's all row deselected.

step 3: suppose user select row3 and row 5 from section 3 and then press done button

step 4: now I want to store row's value (name) in an array.

my code is as below,

```
extension TradeSelectionController {
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        if isSearching && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return viewModel.filteredCategories?.count ?? 0
        }else{
            return viewModel.categorySkills.count
        }
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if isSearching && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
            
            return viewModel.filteredCategories?[section].skill.count ?? 0
            
        }else{
            let section = viewModel.categorySkills[section]
            return section.skill.count
        }
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TradeSelectionTableViewCell")
        
        if ((cell != nil)) {
            
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "TradeSelectionTableViewCell")
        }
        
        if isSearching && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            
            cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            cell?.textLabel?.text = "(\(String(describing: viewModel.categorySkills[indexPath.section].vName)))"
            
            let text =
                viewModel.filteredCategories?[indexPath.section].skill[indexPath.row].vName
            
            //don't change order , change text size
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = text
            
            
        }else{
            cell?.textLabel?.text = viewModel.categorySkills[indexPath.section].skill[indexPath.row].vName
            
            
        }
        if selectedIngredients.contains(indexPath){
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }else{
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
            cell?.backgroundColor = .none
        }
        
        return cell!
    }
    
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    
            if isSearching && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
                return viewModel.filteredCategories?[section].vName
            }else{
                let titleText = viewModel.categorySkills[section].vName
                return titleText
            }
        }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath.section
        if self.selectedIngredients.contains(indexPath){
            self.selectedIngredients.remove(indexPath)
            totalSkills[indexPath.row] = false
        }else{
            self.selectedIngredients.insert(indexPath)
            totalSkills[indexPath.row] = true
            
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        print(selectedIngredients)
        if lastSelectedIndexPath != nil {
            if lastSelectedIndexPath != indexPath.section {
                selectedIngredients.removeAll()
                print(selectedIngredients)
            }
        }
        
        return indexPath
    }
    //    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //        return 30
    //    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
        
        
        //   headerView.addRoundCorner(10)
        headerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
        label.text = viewModel.categorySkills[section].vName
        label.font = ThemeFonts.font(with: 16, for: .bold)
        label.textColor = ThemeColors.primaryTextColor
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        return headerView
    }
}
```

I have tried like below, but is not working....

```
   @objc private func doneAction(_ sender: Any?) {
        
        var selectedSkills = [Skill]()
        if let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            selectedIndex.forEach({
                //viewModel.categorySkills[indexPath.section].skill[indexPath.row].vName
                //let skill = viewModel.skills[$0.row]
                let skill = filteredObjects[$0.row]
                print(skill)
                //           selectedSkills.append(skill)
            })
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: The most recommended way is to maintain the entire UI states (incl. selection state) in the data model, extra arrays are very bad practice. I can remember having given this advice already.

Comment: @vadian , yes you did, but please follow current question and kindly give hint,

Comment: The purpose of what's being asked is unclear. While there is an answer (flagging the rows in the datasource) it may not be a good answer for whatever it is you're attempting to do. More importantly, the tableView knows what rows you've selected so why isn't `doneAction` working? Is there an error? Do you possibly have the tableView set up for single selection only? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Simply add another boolean property named `selected` in your Class Object which it seems you already have. Use that property to maintain selection.

Comment: @Jay , **tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows** result is nil even I select any row and click done button.

Comment: Well, if that's nil then the issue lies elsewhere. Possibly the tableView is not connected in the UI, or perhaps you have a different tableView in code or a myriad of other things. You'll need to do some additional troubleshooting, like stepping through your code, to determine the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a selected flag to the struct that represents cells in your data model.(For sectioned table view a 2-dimensional array of structs works well as a data model.)

Maintain that flag in your code that responds to the user selecting cells.